# Link Multiple Facebook Accounts with 1 Instagram Account

Tags: android, facebook, instagram, user-accounts, multiple-accounts

Is there any way to link multiple Facebook accounts into one Instagram account? I've tried unlinking my 1st Facebook account from Instagram hoping that I can link it with my 2nd Facebook account but Instagram said that I already have linked it (my IG) to a Facebook account thus disallowing me to do so. Could it be possible to link multiple Facebook accounts with only one IG account or not, just one FB account?

Just wondering,

Mark

Comment: I don't think so you are allowed to link multiple facebook accounts into one Instagram account.

Comment: You are not supposed to have more than one Facebook user account in the first place.